Do the protons at the LHC have a lower Luminosity than they would if they collided with antiprotons?
Do the charges on the particles colliding at a collider measurable affect the ease with which they collide?
I have read a lot about why the LHC collides protons with other protons rather than protons with antiprotons like they did at Fermilab's Tevatron, but....
Do the repelling positive charges noticeably reduce the 'luminosity', or rate at which collisions actually happen?

No.  An interaction via a repulsive interaction is still a collision.
Collisions at the LHC are energetic enough that the nucleon-nucleon interaction has nontrivial contributions from pion exchange and other meson exchanges; these strong interactions are generally more important to the collision dynamics than the charge-sensitive electromagnetic interactions.
